# Drive Maps via Group Policy - Overlapping Policies

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, group-policy, active-directory

((NOTE: We are on Windows 8.1 with a 2008R2 domain))

We have decided to move away from mapping drives via a log in script and attempting to do it via Group Policy. I have personally been doing this on my account for a few months now to see what how it would effect my day to day. For me, it was fine, no issues. I had my own Group Policy that would apply to me through GPP by targeting my self.

We created a new GPO so I could show how it worked to a coworker. Once we had it how we liked it, with all the GPP objects targeting us here in IT, I had my coworker delete the old testing GPO that targeted me.

That's when things got weird. We now getting some drive mappings that I **know** were part of the GPO that we deleted. I've taken my computer off the domain to flush my cached group policies, and I'm still getting a mix of drive mappings.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: We'll need more information.  Use GPResult to determine if/how they are being applied via GP. If they don't show up in the GPP settings list, then they are either being added by a script, or they are drive mapped locally on the computer.

Answer (score 3):

If you did not tick the "Remove this item when it is no longer applied" box on the "Common" tab of the Drive Map Group Policy Preferences entry then, by default, the preference will persist even after the GPO no longer applies.